# Convert large XTS object to array to calculate Eignevalues and Eigenvectors

Tags: r, matrix, xts, eigenvalue, wavelet-transform

I have a large XTS object which is the result of a correlation calculation using a sliding window across an XTS ZOO object of 12 x 12 variables for 1343 data points in time.

My large XTS object is structured as follows, rows represent time and columns represent the correlation combinations. A simplified example is shown below:

```
    AA  BA  CA   AB  BB  CB   AC  BC  CC
t1  1   .1  -.4  .1  1   .3  -.4  .3   1
t2  1   .4  .8   .4  1   .2   .8  .2   1
t3  1   .5  .5   .5  1   .3   .5  .3   1
t4  1   .6  .1   .6  1   .7   .1  .7  .1
```

Correct me if I'm wrong but I believe the `eigen()` function in R requires a square matrix to calculate the eigenvalues of the matrix lambda 1,2 and 3?

How can I square the xts object above to find the eigenvalues and vectors with each matrix across time?

I'm guessing I'll have a matrix for each time period (1-4) in the XTS object above and the matrix should be constructed by taking the first 3 values (1 .1 -.4) and putting them into the first column, again the next three values (.1 1 .3) and this goes into the second column and finally the last three values of row one (-.4 .3 1) go into the last column to make up the 3 x 3 matrix which is shown below:

matrix for t1

```
   A   B   C
A   1 .1 -.4
B  .1  1  .3
C -.4 .3   1
```

Maybe the transformation from the XTS object is not required to calculate the eigenvalues but if I step through it in my head these are the steps required to calculate the eigenvalues for my XTS  object.

Ideally the eigenvalues from each matrix would then be stored in a dataframe or matrix, in the case above I would have a dataframe of 12 observations of 3 variables or a matrix of 3 x 4.

Can anyone tell me if I'm going about this the wrong way and whether `eigen()` can take the XTS object in it's current form and calculate the eigenvalues?

[dput](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxgkBr1CkDf7TEt3YkRObTlULVk/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For demonstration purposes, I'm only returning the greatest of the eigenvalues set, but you can modify the code to return anything you need.

```
library(xts)
dfx <- structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, -0.4, 0.8, 0.5, 0.1, 
0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.3, 0.2, 0.3, 0.7, -0.4, 0.8, 
0.5, 0.1, 0.3, 0.2, 0.3, 0.7, 1, 1, 1, 1), .Dim = c(4L, 9L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("AA", "BA", "CA", "AB", "BB", "CB", "AC", "BC", "CC"
    )), index = structure(c(1167685200, 1167771600, 1167858000, 
1167944400), tzone = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "", tzone = "", class = c("xts", 
"zoo"))

apply.daily(dfx, function(x) eigen(matrix(x, nrow = sqrt(length(x))))$values[1])
#               [,1]
#2007-01-02 1.455287
#2007-01-03 1.984869
#2007-01-04 1.872842
#2007-01-05 1.972804
```

Comment: thanks so much for the quick reply, much appreciate. I see from the help in R that there are a number of apply functions for distinct time period i.e weekly, daily, monthly etc but my data is actually 15 min data, is there another function that can handle this kind of granularity? BTW I changed values[1] to values[1:12] to return the 12 eigenvalues I needed.

Comment: @PigWolf You can specify arbitrary periods using `period.apply` instead. Or use base `apply(dfx, 1, ...)` and then convert back to xts.

Comment: great thanks, I am getting a little bit stuck on the section for the number of rows in the matrix. If I interpret this incorrectly please let me know. From left to right, for each daily value of dfx you apply a function x which calculates the eigenvalues of a matrix with nrows = 6 since the length of x or dfx is 36 (4*9). Although when I run your code on dfx there's only 4 rows of data so I'm confused about the matix set up. BTW my data has 144 columns and 1343 rows so the sqrt doesn't work for me. I've also added a dput to the original post as this is hard to convey.

Comment: @PigWolf No -- I do what you describe in the post: take the whole row (9 values), compose a matrix (sqrt(9) -- size 3x3), run `eigen` on it, repeat this procedure for each day. If you have 144 columns, cormatrices are 12x12, so the same code should work fine.

Comment: I had a bunch of NA values at the start of my xts object which I removed with na,rm(). I also modified it slightly as I couldn't get length(x) to work since length of dfx is 36. I am using `eigen <- apply(slidingCornoNA, 1, function(x) eigen(matrix(x, nrow = sqrt(ncol(slidingCornoNA))))$values[1:12])` . Thanks for your help.